# Add Control Dynamically in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, toolbox

I am trying to use `winform` to replicate this excel table:

[image: Excel Sample]

```
// TableLayoutPanel Initialization
   TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
   panel.ColumnCount = 14;
   panel.RowCount = 2;
   panel.Controls.Add(new Textbox() { Text = "Address" }, 1, 0);
   panel.Controls.Add(new Textbox() { Text = "Contact No" }, 2, 0);
   panel.Controls.Add(new Textbox() { Text = "Email ID" }, 3, 0);
```

In a windows form, I can add control dynamically by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
Button button = new Button();
button.Location = new Point(160, 30 * i + 10);

button.Tag = i;
this.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

How do I add controls dynamically in a `TableLayoutPanel` while keeping all the `textbox` controls and loop through each record?

Comment: `for (int r = 0; r < panel.RowCount; r++) for (int c = 0; c < panel.ColumnCount; c++) {   panel.Controls.Add(new Textbox() { Text = [DataTable].Rows[r][c].ToString() }, c, r); }`. Are you sure a TableLayoutPanel is the right choice? It won't be easy to handle changes in the data (since you're using TextBoxes and not Labels, I assume...). There are othe controls that can show Data in a Grid and let you design custom Views while preserving the *connection* with the data source.

Comment: hi @Jimi, I am able to display the data seamlessly using `ListView`, but it doesn't allow the customization of the excel table... do you have any recommendation?

Comment: There are no standard controls that can reproduce the layout of a Spreadsheet, in WinForms. You *could* use a DataGridView instead, but forget about that kind of *presentation*, unless you want to get your hands dirty with CellPainting, RowPrePaint/RowPostPaint etc. You can find some open source controls that implement this functionality (to an extent). But, this layout is usually meant for presentation, not interaction (to modify the data). If you just need to present the data then, sure, you could use a TableLayoutPanel. Or use a DataGridView with a less *fancy* layout otherwise.

Comment: If you opt for a TLP, you have to pre-filter the data to generate the groupings, to then determine which Control spans more than one Row or more than one Column. It'll be really hard to support data changes in this context (unless very simple ones, targeting specific, bound, Controls). IMO, better use this kind of layout just *for show* (data presentation, not editing).